# How to make one item stay the same size all the time and let only another one shrink when using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem when I use a flex container with two items inside. I want the first one to have the same width all the time and I want only the other one to change size according to the width of the flex container. The solution I found seems to work perfectly when I use Mozilla Firefox but not when I use other browsers (Chrome, Brave, Edge...).

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="hero__container container-primary">
   <div class="hero__content">
      <h1>Are you looking for freelancers?</h1>
      <p class="hero__description body-normal">
         Hire Great Freelancers, Fast. Spacelance helps you hire elite
         freelancers at a moment's notice
      </p>
   </div>
   <img class="hero__image" src="./img/hero-image.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.hero__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  .hero__content {
    width: 634px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }

  .hero__image {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 578px;
  }
}
```

In Mozilla Firefox it behaves exactly the way I want it to as I manually shrink the width of the screen using Developer Tools. However in Google Chrome, Brave and Microsoft Edge the `class="hero__content"` element and the `class="hero__image"` element both overflow the `class="hero__container"` element. Which is not what I'm looking for.

Here is what it looks like in Mozilla Firefox:
[image]

Here is what it looks like in Brave:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the image has a `min-width` of "auto".  If you explicitly set it to 0, this will allow the image to shrink beyond its actual size.

```
  .hero__image {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 578px;
    min-width: 0;
  }
```